# KiesPDLR has stopped working

Tags: samsung-kies, application-autoupdate, system-error

Why after recent Kies update to Ver.2.1.1.11124_17 I get this message?
Though Kies continues to run it is no longer possible to update firmware.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Kies v2.3. If you've found a solution since then, I'd be interested to hear it.

Answer (score -2):

You should uninstall Microsoft .NET 4

Comment: Why? Without information about how this will help this is not a good answer.